# How to create a calendar with task count?

Tags: 2010, calendar

I need to create a calendar for 4-5 set tasks that get assigned to a set group of 40-50 individuals. That part's easy enough, but I also need to be able to show a WTD and MTD count of each task assignment (in other words, something that shows that Person A did Task B 4 times this week).

I know how to do this by manually creating each task entry, but this is something that needs to be done daily for each individual, and that can quickly become overwhelming. Ideally, I'd like to be able to pre-populate a list of users, and the client can open a dropdown box to select the task for the user, choose a start/stop time, and be done with it. The results would appear in a Calendar view, and as long as the count is there it's not important what form that takes. Is this something doable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it can be done with a simple list that has fields for User (choice field), start date with time, end date with time.

The client enters the data.

Create a calendar view on the list. For more detailed analysis you may want to export the list to Excel and run counts per user per day with pivot tables.